# Terraform unknown provider packages

Tags: terraform

I am looking to move the backend to S3. Running the below:

terraform init

Which results in:

```
Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "~> 4.16"...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/server...
- Installing hashicorp/aws v4.67.0...
- Installed hashicorp/aws v4.67.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
╷
│ Error: Failed to query available provider packages
│ 
│ Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/server: provider registry registry.terraform.io does not have a provider named registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/server
│ 
│ All modules should specify their required_providers so that external consumers will get the correct providers when using a module. To see which modules are currently depending on hashicorp/server,
│ run the following command:
│     terraform providers
```

When I run terraform providers I get:

```
Providers required by configuration:
.
├── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws] ~> 4.16
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/server]

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws]
```

I'm unable to find any reference to a provider server, so not sure how I can resolve this.

This is how I'm currently setting my provider:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.16"
    }
  }

  required_version = ">= 1.2.0"
}
```

After process of elimination I have discovered the issue is with this file which is creating an s3 bucket. Not to sure which bit is incorrect.

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform-state" {
 bucket = "terrafrom-state-992292"
 acl    = "private"
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "versioning-terrafrom-state" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terrafrom-state-992292.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
 resource "server_side_encryption_configuration" "ssec_terrafrom-state-992292" {
   rule {
     apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
       kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.terrafrom-state-992292-bucket-key.arn
       sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
     }
   }
 }

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "block" {
 bucket = aws_s3_bucket.terrafrom-state-992292.id

 block_public_acls       = true
 block_public_policy     = true
 ignore_public_acls      = true
 restrict_public_buckets = true
}
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code you have to the question?

Comment: I have added the problem file to the end of my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with this resource:

```
 resource "server_side_encryption_configuration" "ssec_terrafrom-state-992292" {
   rule {
     apply_server_side_encryption_by_default {
       kms_master_key_id = aws_kms_key.terrafrom-state-992292-bucket-key.arn
       sse_algorithm     = "aws:kms"
     }
   }
 }
```

It is looking for a resource named `server` because that is the first part of the name for that resource. The name should be `aws_s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration` as documented [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_server_side_encryption_configuration), not `server_side_encryption_configuration`. You can't modify or shorten the resource names in Terraform, you must use the full name of a resource, exactly as shown in the documentation.